# NoClassDefFoundError : com.android.uiautomator.core.Configurator

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I imported Configurator package in UI Automator which works with API Level 18 :

```
package com.android.uiautomator.core.Configurator;
```

but when I run code , it gives me

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : com.android.uiautomator.core.Configurator
```

In Project properties , target is set to 18 and also in Android_manifest.xml , target sdk version is 18.

Tried everything but it isn't working.
                                                                                         Screenshots are attached of my 'Libraries' , 'Order and Export' folders under Java Build Path and error command prompt.

Orders and Export -

[image: orders-export]

Libraries screenshot -

[image: libraries]

Error in cmd - 
[image: cmd]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Project build target` or `targetSdk` only determine which android version is used to compile your project or device visibility on Googe Play, **but**, is the device android OS which runs the code, so you'll need to run your project in an Android device (or AVD) compliant with `Api Level 18` (`Android 4.3`)

Comment: Thanks , it worked. I was running 4.2.2 in my Nexus 7 device.